# how to copy an item which is in the newest folder in one directory to another

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy a file from the newest folder in on directory to another folder. I have made the code below but it seems that the copy-item command does not work with variables. Does anyone have any other ideas?

```
# Code to get newest directory

$newestFolder = gci \\Server123\sharepoint\HCL\HCL-SUPPORT-SHARED\REPORTING\CAPACITY-PLANNING\ | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime -desc | select -f 1

<# get the latest created folder from a path #>


# Copy folder to a folder with different name

Copy-Item $newestFolder.FullName -Destination "\\Server123\sharepoint\HCL\HCL-SUPPORT-SHARED\REPORTING\CAPACITY-PLANNING\SP Capacity Planning" -Recurse
```

Error Message:

```
Copy-Item : Cannot find path '\\Server123\sharepoint\HCL\HCL-SUPPORT-SHARED\REPORTING\CAPACITY-PLANNING\SP Capacity Planning\Average-Action.csv' because it does not exist. At line:26 char:1 + Copy-Item -Path $sourcedirectory\Average-Action.csv -Destination $tar ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (\\Server123...rage-Action.csv:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNo tFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Copy-Item : Cannot find path '\Server123\sharepoint\HCL\HCL-SUPPORT-SHARED\REPORTING\CAPACITY-PLANNING\S P Capacity Planning\MaxDuration20.csv' because it does not exist. At line:47 char:1 + Copy-Item -Path $sourcedirectory1\MaxDuration20.csv -Destination $tar ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: what makes you think it doesn't work with variables? what doesn't work? Do you get an error message - if so please include it. Else please explain what goes wrong. You'll never find a file in your `gci` because you filter only Directories with `$_.PSIsContainer`

Comment: So if i do not user "gci" then what do i use?

Comment: The code you shared worked fine for me.  You'll need to share more details of the script to troubleshoot further.  Based on the errors, it seems like you're having an issue with a specific file.  Any chance another job is deleting a file between the time gci determines the newest folder and copy-item gets to the file in question to attempt the copy?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that you are actually copying a directory to a directory, because the error you posted is using a file name instead of a folder.

Try the following using your paths:

```
$sourcefolder = '\\path\to\folder\'
$targetfolder = '\\path\to\target\'
$newestfolder = gci -Directory $sourcefolder | sort CreationTime -desc | select -f 1  ## get the newest folder
copy -recurse $newestfolder $targetfolder
```

Comment: I TRIED YOU APPROACH BUT tHE COMMAD FOR COPYING IS NOT WORKING.
$sourcefolder = '\\path\to\folder\'
$targetfolder = '\\path\to\target\'
$newestfolder = gci -Directory $sourcefolder | sort CreationTime -desc | select -f 1  ## get the newest folder
Copy-Item -Path $newestfolder -Destination $targetfolder -Recurse

Comment: ERROR:

copy-Item : Cannot find path '.......PathInQuestion......' because it does not exist.
At line:6 char:1
+ Copy-Item -Path $newestfolder -Destination " \\path\to\target\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.......PathInQuestion......) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Is this error an access issue?

Comment: try and do `get-item` for the path and see if powershell gives a more specific error. If the path is above the max character length, you may get this error.

Comment: the path is less then "Powershell Overcoming 260 character path limit. 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters." Thus... can get-item except a variable as a path?

Comment: yes, `get-item $newestfolder` should work fine. You only need to look for the error causing your `copy-item` to fail. It may be permissions, or a few other reasons. It will be helpful to know if you can read and copy a "bad" item by itself.